MCQ: Non-negative series convergence question
Q: Let $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be a non-negative series. Which implication is true? 
[A] If the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges as well.  $\leftarrow$
(B) If the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^5$, is convergent, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges as well.
(C) If we allow arbitrary terms in $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, then at least one of the implications above remains true.

Can someone please explain how they would've approached and quickly answered this question? Why is a) the solution? Is this not just the comparison test? If so, wouldn't they be claiming $a_n^2 ≤ a_n$, true iff $|a_n| \leq 1$ (but why are we able to assume this?)

because if $\sum_{n}a_n$ is convergent, then $a_n\to 0$.

You probably misunderstand the comparison test, let me state it again:

(Comparison Test) Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are non-negative for all $n$ and $a_n\leq b_n$ when $n\geq N$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$. If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ also converges.

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$, thus there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq \mathbb{N}$, we have $|a_n-1|<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon>0$. Then use the comparison test gives $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ for all $n\geq N$.
I like to use $p$-series as counter-examples. For example, in $B$, take $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{2/5}}$.
For $C$, if we allow arbitrary terms, then consider the counter-example $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$.
